# Detect similar images using PHP with perceptual hashing or other technology

Tags: php, image, hash, similarity, detect

I have 20 JPG images:

[image]

I need to detect this 10 similar images:

[image]

I tried to use **[Perceptual hash implementation for PHP](https://github.com/xwiz/phash)** with above code:

```
<?php

    $scandir = array_values(array_diff(scandir("images"), array(".", "..", ".DS_Store")));
    natsort($scandir);

    include('phash.php');

    foreach ($scandir as $key => $value){
    $phasher = new Phash;

    $phash2 = $phasher->getHash("image-fragment-to-compare.jpg", false);
    echo $phasher->hashAsString($phash2, false).PHP_EOL;
    echo $phasher->hashAsString($phash2).PHP_EOL;

    $phash3 = $phasher->getHash("images/$value", false);
    echo $phasher->hashAsString($phash3, false).PHP_EOL;
    echo $phasher->hashAsString($phash3).PHP_EOL;

    $compare = $phasher->getSimilarity($phash2, $phash3);
    echo "compare image-fragment-to-compare.jpg with images/$value = $compare \n";
    }

?>
```

I tried to use different `image-fragment-to-compare.jpg` fragments such as "keyboard" fragment, "lightning key" fragment, grey background. It detects not bad, but not ideal. Is there any other soultions for PHP that can detect these images more accurate?

Comment: php is a terrible language to do this in

Comment: you could suggest other languages and programs to do this task, thank you

Comment: something in the **c** family